# How do I purchase the Gift merit for different tiers of mystery?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, hunter-the-vigil

The rules state, from Hunter: the Vigil  - Witch Finders on the Gifted merit

> The character may select one spell with a dot rating equal to the Gifted Merit rating from the Mysteries section as a Gift

Does this mean a one dot tier one mystery costs the same as  a one  dot tier three mystery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they cost the same amount *to buy*, but the fact missed is that tier two spells inflict bashing damage on the Gifted, tier three inflicts lethal. Lore spells likely act as tier one abilities.